# Page alignment in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, memory-management, allocator

In Windows I can allocate 64K of virtual memory and the returned memory will be aligned to the 64K boundary.

This is useful as I can round down any address in my memory allocator to the 64K boundary and cast it to a "page header" where I keep booking information.

I would like to do the same in Linux, but it seems I can only do this for the page size (usually 4K).

Is there any way to ask the Linux OS to give me, let's say 16K or 8K but aligned to the same boundary?

Comment: Have you looked at `posix_memalign`?

Comment: I would like to manage the pages myself (mmap). Linux heap let me down, I had to end up using jemalloc while in Windows, the heap as it is rocks in most scenarios. 
I'm thinking on using large pages instead.

Comment: Linux makes it cheap to keep large, mostly unused allocations, and you can drop subranges with `madvise`. A Linux native solution would likely do that instead of trying to allocate 64k at a time.

Comment: You can also create a large aligned area with sbrk and some arithmetic.